# Calculated Column on SharePoint Online Does not appear on New Item

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-columns

On SharePoint Online, I have a form which requires a user to input values into 3 columns

Column 1: Quantity = Column type is Number
Column 2: Unit Cost = Column type is Currency
Column 3: Calculated Column which is Quantity into Unit Cost

When I click on New Item or New Form, It displays Column 1 and 2 i.e., Quantity and Unit Cost but it does not display the Calculated Column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to clarify one point with you, the calculated column will not be shown in the New Item, it is automatically calculated by the system background, you can not input the value.